# I am trying to use the in-built application settings with user-scope in vs 2013. They are not being saved. Any tips?

Tags: c#, properties

```
            string transSet = txtSetting.Text;
            Properties.Settings.Default.strLevDeci = transSet;
            Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

If l then try to retrieve the setting value, l get the default still.`

```
        Properties.Settings.Default.Reload();
        txtSetting.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.strLevDeci;`
```

I have tried tons of the solutions from research but l am not getting any change.

Comment: Don't call the `.Reload();` method. Read the [Remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.configuration.applicationsettingsbase.reload?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0#remarks) section of this method. Just assign the values and call `.Save();`.

Comment: Thanks, it has also made the code shorter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you very much. I kept on attempting new ways and realized the simple mistake that l was making. Instead of supplying the setting as an argument to a method that assigns it a value, one is supposed to assign a value directly in the method that requires such an operation.